# Azure AD Saml response to web application not provided

Tags: c#, azure, saml, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have followed this tutorial from microsoft below to create an app that links to my web application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps

I have also set the SSO to be Windows Azure AD SSO, but when i use the portal to click the application, i recieve no SAML response inside `Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]`but it does correctly link to my website.

I have done the exact same process on the website https://www.OneLogin.com and all works fine and the SAMLResponse is receive.

So my Questions is does anybody know why after following the tutorial above i am not receiving the SAMLResponse within `Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]` and it is just coming back null??

Cheers,

Comment: What is the question here? What problem are you facing here?

Comment: Actually question added to the original text

Comment: You can try using SAML tracer plug in of GoogleChrome to observe the SAML request and response happening during login flow. You can check until what point the SAML data comes and where it get lost. Also using fiddler to trace down the request and to see what data is sumbitted and what data comes back as response would be help you to narrow down the problem area.

Comment: It seems like the request from Azure has no SAML contained??

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, were you able to figure this one out? I suspect that I must be missing something in my Azure settings to send back a SAML response.

Comment: @bobby Did you ever figure this out?